Why Does Computable Analysis Use Type 2 Turing Machines Over Type 1 TM's?
I've been researching formal models for computing with real numbers and came across the field of computable analysis built on top of specifically the type 2 Turing machine, which allows for technically infinite outputs and infinite inputs given the restriction that every finite but unbounded subsequence of the output was computed given some finite but unbounded portion of the input. At first I accepted this based on the notion that using t2tm's 1. cant solve the halting problem even given this boost, and 2. t2tm's make it easier to work with the notion of inputs and outputs of particular machines whereas the definition of computable numbers for t1tm's is pretty awkward. A t1tm calculates pi by being given a number of digits to compute in the input, and halts after writing exactly that many digits of pi, a t2tm calculates pi by writing pi forever and so long as it continues to be correct we say pi is t2 computable.
This seems much more straightforward, especially if you say wanted to reason about composing functions based on multiple computable but irrational numbers. But then I realized that 1. given a t1tm that computes n digits of irrational number I and a t1tm that multiplies the input by 10, theres trivially a t1tm that computes n+2 digits of 10I, so composability while conceptually awkward is analytically trivial, and 2. while t1tm's require finite but arbitrarily low inaccuracy in any one number of digits to output, t2tm's allow for 0 inaccuracy for computable sequences at the cost of infinite time to finish. Infinite precision at the cost of infinite time doesn't seem to allow for composing t2tm's together (just wait forever until the function returns). Likewise embedding the composition of two t2tm's in one should still be analytically trivial, but it doesn't seem to be much different from normal turing machines.
So why does computable analysis define and continue to use t2 turing machines? is it literally just that it's easier to work with something that can produce all of a representation of an irrational number as opposed to a finite but unbounded approximation of one or is there something I'm missing about why they're more useful as a formal model of computation on the reals?

Let's clarify the two models, looking at the definition of computability for a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (because looking at individual real numbers is too simple a case to be illuminating).
The Type-2 perspective: The function $f$ is computable, if there is a machine receiving a (code for) a sequence of rationals $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $|q_n - x| < 2^{-n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ will write a sequence of rationals $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $|r_n - f(x)| < 2^{-n}$.
The Oracle-TM perspective: The function $f$ is computable, if there is a machine receiving as input some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as well as access to an oracle, which if queried at $m \in \mathbb{N}$ will return some $q_m$ with $|q_m - x| < 2^{-m}$, will eventually halt and return some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $|r - f(x)| < 2^{-n}$.
Both definitions are easily seen to coincide. The Type-2 perspective has a simpler control flow, but makes more explicit use of infinite objects and computations, the Oracle-TM perspective has the opposite drawbacks and advantages. As long as you are interested in computable functions on separable metric spaces (or more generally, on Quasi-Polish spaces), there isn't any objective reason to prefer one over the other.
If you want to work with more general spaces, the Oracle-TM perspective becomes cumbersome. This is because you no longer have a notion of "approximating up to precision $n$"; you really need to consider the entire name at once to decode its meaning.
On the other hand, if you want to do complexity theory, the Oracle-TM has the advantage of offering random access to the input. This again doesn't matter for real numbers as input, but if your input is eg a function $f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1],[0,1])$, you really want to query it at different places independently.

Why is an oracle necessary here for printing out finite approximations of computable numbers on t1 machines?

@KylerAce The oracle is needed to provide the input real number.

do we need an oracle to approximate computable (though irrational) numbers like pi to arbitrary precision or are we just using oracles to allow for computing approximations to uncomputable numbers
